# Does "or {}" work in python like in javascript?

Tags: python

This was my first code:

```
def __init__(self, attrs=None):
    if not attrs:
        attrs = {}
    attrs['data-select2-json'] = "true"
```

Then I tried like in JavaScript:

```
def __init__(self, attrs=None):
    attrs = attrs or {}
    attrs['data-select2-json'] = "true"
```

It seems to work, but I'm wondering: does "or {}" work in python like in javascript? (hard times googling this!) and is it as fast as the simple "`if`" of my first code?

Comment: If attrs is any falsey value line `False`, `0`, `[]` etc.. then attrs will always end up a dict.

Comment: It produces to different output when changes `print False or {}
 gives {}` and `print {} or False gives False`  you could use using first case but there are problems like padric has commented.

Comment: both your snippets are also identical from a logic perspective, if you change to `if  attrs is not None:` then attrs would only be a dict if you passed one in, you passed in nothing or you explicitly passed in None

Comment: It's called "short-circuiting." And yes.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Short-circuiting has nothing really to do with this question.

Comment: @deceze - Looking at this question and that one, and this one's answers and that one's answers, it looks like it's exactly what this is. Can you explain why they're totally unrelated?

Comment: @Olivier, to get a definitive answer maybe you should describe how it works in javascript

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 *Those* answers explained short-circuiting, meaning that not all operands are always evaluated. This here is about boolean equality and/or performance.

Comment: @deceze - I thought "One more interesting point to note :- Logical and, or operators in Python returns operand's value instead of Boolean True, False for example: In the case of and, if the left-hand side is equivalent to False, the right-hand side is not evaluated, and the left-hand value is returned." took care of explaining boolean equality (key: "equivalent"). And personally, I see this question as being about short-circuiting, as that's what the code is doing.

Comment: As I commented on soons answer, using a node repl `null || {} -> {}` but `[] || {} -> []` so based on that it is not the same as python

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - That in particular is due to how the [empty array is evaluated in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5491605/empty-arrays-seem-to-equal-true-and-false-at-the-same-time) (briefly, JS arrays are instances of `Object`, and, like in Python, any instance of `object` evaluates to truthy). The short-circuiting concept is the same, and there's no empty array or `list` here anyway.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, there is if one gets passed in. That is what the OP is asking, if python behaves the same as js which it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.

This means, that both of your codes does the same thing:

```
if not attrs:
    attrs = {}
```

Evaluates `attrs`. When `attrs` is true - does nothing, otherwise assigns `{}` to `attrs`

```
attrs = attrs or {}
```

Evaluates `attrs`. When `attrs` is true - assigns `attrs` to `attrs` (not sure about optimizations), otherwise assigns `{}` to `attrs`

---

In JavaScript operator `x || y` also returns `x` when `x` evaluates to true, `y` otherwise. Quote from the [standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf):

> `LogicalORExpression` : `LogicalORExpression || LogicalANDExpression`
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `LogicalORExpression`.
> 2. Let `lval` be `GetValue(lref)`.
> 3. Let `lbool` be `ToBoolean(lval)`.
> 4. [`ReturnIfAbrupt(lbool)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995554/what-does-returnifabrupt-mean-in-es6-draft).
> 5. If `lbool` is true, return `lval`.
> 6. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating `LogicalANDExpression`.
> 7. Return `GetValue(rref)`.

However, you should note [conversions to boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference/JS%3A%3AToBoolean) in JavaScript:

```
> Boolean({})
true
> Boolean([])
true
```

Comment: Is this the same behaviour in js?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Not sure, working on it

Comment: Well FWIW `null || {}` evaluates to `{}` in a node repl but  `[] || {}` evaluates to `[]` so usign that  it is not the same as python

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, this is because `Boolean({})` is `true` in JS, however, `bool({})` is `False` in Python. I've updated the answer with clarifications

Comment: @OlivierPons, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Your first version is more readable for me, but if you insist using one liner, you can use this (from Python 2.5):

```
    attrs = {} if attrs is None else attrs
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still dont know if `attrs = attrs or {}` is a valid Python code, or if your sample is better and most important: *why*. Thank you!

Comment: `attrs = attrs or {}` will assign `{}` if attrs evaluates to False, so if it's an empty dictionary.

Comment: ...which functionally likely makes no difference, really...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the JS-style assignment is valid Python. It stems for the concept of Truthiness in Python.

If you try `a = 0 or 5`, you'll find `a == 5` because `0` is Falsy, but `5` is Truthy. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html) outline what is Falsy.

You might be curious why `{}` is evaluating to a Truthy value in your code when the docs mention it is Falsy: it's because `or` and `and` will return an operand: namely, the last one.

`a = 0 or None or {} or []` will bind `[]` to `a` because of this exception.

In your example, `None` is Falsy, but `{}` is bound because it is the last.

In short, when assigning with `or`, it will assign to the first Truthy value (or the last Falsy one in a string of Falsy values).

```
>>> class Foo:
...   def __init__(self, attrs=None):
...     if not attrs:
...         attrs = {}
...     print(attrs)
... 
>>> Foo(attrs={'1': '2'})
{'1': '2'}
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x1006e5b90>
>>> Foo()
{}
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x1006e59e0>
>>> class Foo:
...   def __init__(self, attrs=None):
...     attrs = attrs or {}
...     print(attrs)
... 
>>> Foo(attrs={'1': '2'})
{'1': '2'}
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x1006e5bd8>
>>> Foo()
{}
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x1006e59e0>
```

Just a caveat, this is not incredibly Pythonic. Typically you'll see

```
a = <default> if cond else a
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still dont if your sample `a = <default> if cond else a`  is better and most important: *why*. Thank you!

Comment: Plenty of downvotes. :)

Comment: @OlivierPons Note the edit should explain `why`.